# Running cron script with lynx fails to work

Tags: shell-script, cron, lynx

I'm trying to automate a login process that can only be done through a browser. I am using the lynx browser to script the actions required to do this. Lynx does this by dumping a user's keystrokes into a file and then it allows a flag: `-cmd_script=scriptfile` to load the script.

I invoke lynx:

```
lynx -accept_all_cookies -cmd_script="myscript.lynx" www.example.com
```

From my interactive terminal, the resulting script works perfectly for me.

I have cron run the task and it doesn't work. I checked /var/log/everything.log and I noticed that when the script ran, lynx asks:

```
Your Terminal type is unknown!
Enter a terminal type: [vt100]
```

To fix this, I used the flag `-term=linux` which stopped the issue, but the login process still did not seem to get past the first page (by looking at the log file).

I've tried as many suggestions as I could find. I copied the results from env (in the interactive terminal) and pasted them into the script to see if the environment would fix it, but alas it did not.

Another note:
My login process involves a redirect (which doesn't redirect in the lynx browser so I just follow the link it gives)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a simple mistake. When I used the flag `-cmd_script="myscript.lynx"`, I had placed `myscript.lynx` in the same directory as the script (which happened to be `/root/bin`). I figured out that lynx was never running the script, the reason being that apparently cron runs from the home directory of the user. Because I was using root's crontab, it was searching `/root` for `myscript.lynx`, not `/root/bin` like I had hoped.

The simple fix? `-cmd_script="/root/bin/myscript.lynx"`